# Why required type of function parameter is assignable to optional type?

Tags: typescript

**Optional Type → Required Type**

```js
const testFunc = (func: (param: number) => void): void => {
  func(3);
};

testFunc((a?: number) => {
  console.log(a);
});
```

**Required Type → Optional Type**

```js
const testFunc = (func?: (param: number) => void): void => {
  func(3);
};

testFunc((a: number) => {
  console.log(a);
});
```

In the above examples, why doesn't TypeScript throw a type error?

**Update**

Let's think abount specific example in React. I have handler function which parameters are required type. But, when I pass this handler function to props as component which types are optional. It cannot be inferred. It occur problem when important logic  is dealed in handler function. Because parameters could be nullable.

Comment: Your second example does not compile. Did you mean `const testFunc = (func: (param?: number)`...?

Comment: I'd expect the first one to succeed because the function *does* accept a number, but the second one to fail because the function *doesn't* accept undefined.

Comment: @JonasHøgh I tested all codes and compiled/executed successfully

Comment: It's not an error, because you don't have `strict:true`. Check the following [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BiBXMwYF4YAoBmawAXLgA4CGATuQLYlgo0BG8lAlFgHwwBuIAlgBM2JPkK4wA3gCgYMAuhwBmNgG5pAX3XSEyQjhzkA-PUYt2EmXNCQQAG3gA6OyADmhtZs-Sb0OIihUdAAmLFwFYjIqWhMYBmZWDkxuMWFRAUFLWXl9FXUtaR0AoOBgg3JTBItkqWzfeycXd3JPDTUgA), where strict is set, and it will throw an error, like @jonrsharpe expected

Comment: @PoulKruijt I saw your playground, then why first case is valid? I cannot know why

Comment: Because the function accepts either a number or undefined, so is going to be entirely valid in a context where it always receives a number.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for comment, then how can I enforce this typing? Is there way to prevent this? This was problem in production level

Comment: @HaramBae Enforce what? Do you want example 1 or example 2 to fail? Example 1 is perfectly sound, and should not fail. Example 2 will fail with strictNullChecks enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 1**

This is a higher order function whose parameter is a function from `number` to `void`. Passing a function that can also handle undefined numbers to this function works, because `number | undefined` is a wider type than `number`.

**Example 2**

This is also a higher order function whose parameter is a function from `number` to `void`, but the entire function can be undefined. This fails because invoking `func` inside the HOF is illegal if `func` is undefined.

**What I think you meant in example 2**

```
const testFunc = (func: (param?: number) => void): void => {
  func(3);
};

testFunc((a: number) => {
  console.log(a);
});
```

This is a higher order function whose parameter is a function from `number | undefined` to `void`. This fails because the function passed the HOF does not allow the parameter to be `undefined`.

Comment: Then, how can I enforce?

Comment: strictNullChecks: true in your ts config: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

Comment: I added specific circumstance in question

Comment: If you're passing a function into a HOF in a library such as react, and react wants to be able to call that function with an `undefined` parameter, then the code inside your function has to behave correctly when the argument is `undefined`. You cannot solve this by restricting the type in the type system. On the contrary, you should explicitly model the parameter as optional in the type system, so that the compiler forces you to handle `undefined` correctly